# Merge two files in linux and ignore any repetition

Tags: linux, shell

Can anyone provide me with a shell script in linux that merges two files and saves it in a third file. However I want that if there is any common data in both the files then the common lines should only be saved once. Please ask if you need any more details. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is this homework?  You are best off asking how to get something done than asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: It would be nice of you if you even tell that how to get it done..Thanks!!

Comment: What order should the output be in? Is it important?

Comment: No the order is not important.

Comment: in that case, my answer should do the trick...

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way:

```
cat one two | sort -u > third
```

But this is probably not what you want...

You mentioned merging in your question: what do you mean with that? If it's not that simple as I assumed in my code above, provide sample files and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: By merging I want to say that the contents of both files that are not common must be printed and the content that is common is printed only once i.e. same lines should not appear twice. for eg if both the files have 2 lines each out of which the first one is same. So I want that first line to be printed first, then the second line of first file and finally the second line of third file..Hope u got it now..:) Thanks!!